# Adding a Filter / Condition to Histogram in R

Tags: r, filter

I'm trying to do something pretty simple: insert a filter/condition into the `hist` command and I'm trying to figure out what the most efficient way to do this would be.

Command Right Now

```
hist(DTzips2$pctr08zip)
```

I want to limit results to one state (another column in the dataframe) and I'm trying to figure out what language to add to this.

Comment: Maybe something like `hist(DTzips2$pctr08zip[DTzips2$state == "TX"])`.

Comment: `with(subset(DTzips2, state == "FL"), hist(pctr08zip))`?

Comment: Perfect answer, d.b. Embarrassingly, I did not realize I could filter two ways at once inside of histogram.

Frank, your answer worked for me too, but for other reasons, I was trying to avoid subsetting. Seriously, thank you so much though to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221605/cant-draw-histogram-using-dplyr-data-manipulation-x-must-be-numeric) that uses dplyr:

```
yourdata %>% 
  filter(state =="FL") %>% 
  pull(pctr08zip) %>% 
  hist()
```