# Can't draw histogram using dplyr data manipulation: 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to using R for data manipulation, specifically dplyr and I was trying to write a line of code to produce a histogram and it gives me an error that 'x' must be numeric but from what I can tell 'x' is numeric.

A version of the code I am trying to run is as follows with the corresponding error:

```
mydata %>% filter(Type==1) %>% select(Amount) %>% hist()
Error in hist.default(.) : 'x' must be numeric
```

If I change this to a boxplot like as follows it works perfectly fine:

```
mydata %>% filter(Type==1) %>% select(Amount) %>% boxplot()
```

If I just run:

```
mydata %>% filter(Type==1) %>% select(Amount)
```

I get the results below showing the value as a dbl:

```
# A tibble: 898 x 1
Amount
  <dbl>
 1 -1304.  
 2  -741.  
 3   -38.0 
 4    -1.13
 5     0.  
 6     0.  
 7     0.  
 8     0.  
 9     0.  
10     0.  
# ... with 888 more rows**strong text**
```

Also, if I run the following code I get the histogram I am looking for but I am not sure why my original line of code does not work.

```
tmp <- mydata %>% filter(Type==1) %>% select(Amount)
hist(tmp$Amount)
```

I am sure this is something simple that I am missing but I thought that using the select(Amount) statement would pass that value into the hist() function but that does not appear to be happening. The weird part to me is I can change it to a boxplot and it works fine. Any ideas of what is wrong with my original code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?hist` and `?boxplot`, `hist` accepts a numeric vector as data while `boxplot` can accept both numeric vector or lists.

To return a numeric vector from pipe, you can use `pull` to extract the column as a vector, which can be then passed to `hist` for plotting:

```
mydata %>% filter(Type==1) %>% pull(Amount) %>% hist()
```

Comment: Ah well that was easy, I didn't even think that it was passing it as a list and not a vector (still getting used to those data types). Thanks for the help!